# How to write a constructor for a parameterized class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I was wondering if you could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have

```
public class SingleLinkedList<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private class Node
    {
        public T Val;
        public Node Next;
    }

    private Node _root = null; 

    /// <summary>
    ///  Initialize list from array
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public SingleLinkedList<T> (T[] arr)
    {

    }

    // ...

}
```

and my compiler is not liking the `(T[] arr)` and is saying

> Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface declaration

What is the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the generic type parameter:

```
public SingleLinkedList (T[] arr)
{

}
```

The type parameter is part of the class declaration, not part of the constructor declaration.  The constructor's parameter type will be the type used for the class.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the type parameter from the constructor, it's implied:

```
public SingleLinkedList(T[] arr)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add `<T>` to your constructor definition.

```
/// <summary>
///  Initialize list from array
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public SingleLinkedList(T[] arr)
{

}
```